# Map key to itself and another key without overwriting the previous mapping of the key

Tags: vim

I'm writing a plugin and I need to detect when a user uses the `n` key to get to the next search result.

```
nmap n n:echo "detected!"<CR>
```

Unfortunately this overwrites all mappings the user defined for `n`, for example centering on the cursor after jumping to the next search result.

```
nmap n nzz
```

Is there a way to map `n` to whatever the user mapped to `n` and my `echo` command? In this example the result should be equal to:

```
nmap n nzz:echo "detected"<CR>
```

Comment: `:help maparg()`, especially the last paragraph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As melpomene wrote, you can take profit of the `maparg()` function, for example:

```
function! AppendMap(name, mode, rhs)
    let l:oldrhs = maparg(a:name, a:mode)
    exe printf('%smap %s %s', a:mode, a:name, l:oldrhs.a:rhs)
endf

call AppendMap('n', 'n', ':echo "detected"<CR>')
" If key 'n' was mapped to 'nzz', then it is now mapped to 'nzz:echo "detected"<CR>'
```